# Django: fill model's fields with values from another model (at init and save)

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys

I've got 2 models (for the example).

```
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)
    my_name = models.CharField()
```

So, I want to create (and update) the field `my_name` of the instance of B, with the field `name` of the instance of A to which it's related (one to many relation).

I've tried:

```
class B(models.Model):
    ....
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       self.my_name = self.a.name
```

But I've got the error:

```
AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'B' object has no attribute 'a_id'
```

I think it's something related to Django adding a `_id` for foreign key field, so I've tried :

```
class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A, db_column="a")
    ...
```

But I've got the same error.

I'm pretty new to Django. Thx!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try overriding the `save` method on your `B` model:

```
class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)
    my_name = models.CharField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.my_name = self.a.name
        super(B, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: What do you think about using  pre_save signal in this case?