# How to match specific fields on models?

Tags: django, django-models

I have model as below, I need to get **bookname** as **ForeignKey** and it works on Django Admin but I also need **pageCount** related with **bookPageCount** to auto determine on Django Admin or on add new record. When I add new log to **ReadList** I want **pageCount** to define automatically depending on record selected from **Book**;

```py
class Book(models.Model):
    bookname = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Kitap Adı')
    bookAuthor = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Yazar Adı')
    bookPublisher = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Yayın Evi')
    bookPageCount = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name='Sayfa Sayısı')
    bookAddDate = models.DateField(verbose_name='Kitaplığa Eklenme Tarihi')
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Kitap'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Kitaplar' 

class ReadList(models.Model):
    bookName = models.ForeignKey('kitaplik.Book.bookname', related_name='bookName', on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Kitap Adı')
    readerName = models.ForeignKey('ogrenciler.Students.studentName', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='readerName', verbose_name='Okuyan Kişi')
    dateOfRead = models.DateField(verbose_name='Okuma Tarihi')
    pageCount = models.ForeignKey('kitaplik.Book.bookPageCount', related_name='pageCount', on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name='Sayfa Sayısı')
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Okuma Günlüğü'
```

After first answer I imported **post_save** and **reciever** to **models.py** and it is now like this;

```py
class Book(models.Model):
    bookname = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Kitap Adı')
    bookAuthor = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Yazar Adı')
    bookPublisher = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Yayın Evi')
    bookPageCount = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name='Sayfa Sayısı')
    bookAddDate = models.DateField(verbose_name='Kitaplığa Eklenme Tarihi')
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Kitap'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Kitaplar'
    def __str__(self):
        return self.bookname

class ReadList(models.Model):
    bookName = models.ForeignKey('Book', related_name='book', on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Kitap Adı')
    readerName = models.ForeignKey('ogrenciler.Students', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='readerName', verbose_name='Okuyan Kişi')
    dateOfRead = models.DateField(verbose_name='Okuma Tarihi')
    pageCount = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name='Sayfa Sayısı',blank=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Okuma Günlüğü'
@receiver(post_save, sender=ReadList)
def get_pageCount(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.pageCount = instance.book.pageCount
    instance.save
```

Comment: I found the solution here = https://stackoverflow.com/a/25326895/2338774

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, can you write a more concise code, using the `ForeignKey` without repeating the fields.

```
class ReadList(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey('kitaplik.Book', related_name='book', on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Kitap Adı')
    readerName = models.ForeignKey('ogrenciler.Students.studentName', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='readerName', verbose_name='Okuyan Kişi')
    dateOfRead = models.DateField(verbose_name='Okuma Tarihi')
        class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Okuma Günlüğü'
```

Next, you can use `ReadList.book.pageCount` in your views or in your template.

**EDIT**
If you want to store the value of `book.pageCount`as a separate value in your your `ReadList` object, you can launch a signal after each ReadList creation:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=ReadList)
def get_pageCount(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.pageCount = instance.book.pageCount
    instance.save
```

Comment: Yeah but I want pageCount to be stored on ReadList table.

Comment: I think this is right way but something is missing I get following error;
`Exception Value: 'ReadList' object has no attribute 'book'`

Comment: Given the model you have posted, maybe should you replace `bookName` with `book`

Comment: I passed the error new code is `instance.pageCount = instance.bookName.bookPageCount` but now I am getting `maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison`

Comment: Can you hare the full traceback please?

Comment: Thank you Aurelien but I found the solution here = https://stackoverflow.com/a/25326895/2338774